# Unable to duplicate rigged object

Tags: objects, rigging

I have a rigged object but when I duplicate it the reference cursor still has control over it, thereby mutilating the object.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The rig needs to be removed from parent therefore select object AlT+P remove parent
https://youtu.be/lVq74a8nD8I